# C Beginner question: Pointer to a pointer / Can't access values from outside a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm passing a pointer to a pointer (**resultSet) to my MySQL function.

Here's an excerpt on how I copy the MySQL data from within the function:

```
int
getItems(char * cmd, char **resultSet)
{

...
MYSQL initialisations and set-up
...



    resultSet = malloc(sizeof(char)*(int)mysql_num_rows);

    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
    {

            for (i=0 ; i < mysql_num_fields(result); i++)               
            {   
            printf("%i: \t", i);        
            resultSet[counter] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(row[i])+1);
            strcpy(resultSet[counter], row[i]);
            printf("%s\n", resultSet[counter]);
            }
            printf("---------------------\n");
            counter++;      
    }
...
MYSQL cleaning up
...
return 0;
}
```

Calling it in main with

```
getItems(cmd, resultSet);
```

From within my getItems function this

```
printf("%s\n", resultSet[0]);
```

seems to work.

However, if I try to access it from outside my function I get a segmentation fault. Why is this?

Comment: We have to see the calling and function decl to be able to answer this.

Comment: `sizeof(void)` looks wrong.  Maybe you want `sizeof(void*)`?  Furthermore, your code does not change the pointer `resultSet` points to at all.

Comment: What is sizeof(void)? Do you want sizeof(void*) or am I lacking some knowledge?

Comment: It's still wrong though - should be `sizeof(char *)`

Comment: Yes, you all got it right. It should be sizeof(char *) because I'm want the size of my char pointer, not a char itself. I tried both and they seem to work, but I assume it's only because char eats more memory. I wanted to keep the listing where with the wrong malloc so another beginner who sees this could learn from it as well. My third reply was actually for Hogans comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use resultSet as a return parameter, you need to make the function signature

```
int getItems(char * cmd, char ***resultSet)
```

and use it in the function like

```
*resultSet = malloc(sizeof(char)*(int)mysql_num_rows)
```

The function call could look like

```
char** results;
nitems = getItems(somecmd, &results);
```

Better and simpler is probably to leave it as it is and make the allocation before the function call.

Comment: You are right. I still don't understand, why does ***resultSet work and **resultSet doesn't?

Comment: Consider a simple function, where you want to return a value given as parameter. To accomplish this, you need to make the parameter a pointer to the value you want to return and in the function assign to the location the pointer points to the value you want to return. The same is here, you want to return an array of strings, in C this is a `char**`. To make this work you need to introduce an additional level of indirection and pass a `char***`, which is a pointer to an array of strings. *All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection* - Butler Lampson

Comment: More and more I'm getting the hang of it. Many thanks that you took the time to explain it to me! Frank

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
resultSet = malloc(sizeof(void *)*(int)mysql_num_rows);
```

Instead of:

```
resultSet = malloc(sizeof(void)*(int)mysql_num_rows);
```

as you need pointers not bytes.

Comment: Even better would be `sizeof(char *)`, because thats what a single element of resultSet actually is

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here:

- As indicated the allocation of resultset is wrong.
- Secondly, strlen(row[i]+1) will calculate the string length of the memory location referenced by row[i]+1. This length will be 1 less then the string length of row[i]. Since you're basically duplicating a null terminated string, use that function: `resultSet[counter] = strdup((char *)row[i]);`

No need to malloc and strcpy.

Comment: Thanks Mel, I will try the strdup function. However, in my strlen the row[i] part is within () so the +1 means "add one to the result of the number you receive from strlen once you got it". I might have got it wrong as I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you have an array of char arrays that you want to fill with your data. Your initial allocation should be changed to:

```
resultSet = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(int)mysql_num_rows);
```

To reflect this (notice char*).

Also:

```
resultSet[counter] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(row[i])+1);
```

This row is technically correct, but you should change it to:

```
resultSet[counter] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(row[i])+1) );
```

To reflect what you actually want to do (the reason for this is the order that C performs arithmetics, and the first approach would yield wrong results if you tried to do it on any other datatype than char/unsigned char).

Finally, I expect that you want to return the value of the 2d-array somehow. There are two ways to do this:

1. Make the function return a char** (return NULL on failure). You don't need resultSet as an input parameter here.
2. int
   getItems(char * cmd, char ***resultSet)

Notice that everything with resultSet in the function would have to change to *resultSet. The function can then be called with:

```
char **result;
int status = getItems(cmd, &result);
```

Comment: Thanks Orka, I tried both variants and in the malloc function (char *) and (char) both seem to work though I assume that (char) would need more memory. I now returned the resultSet and it all works. Could you please explain why a char ***resultSet (in parameters) works but a **resultSet does not?

Comment: To keep this short: Both your questions relate to the difference between a memory address and the data that is stored there. The comment field is to short to explain this, please look up some online resource on C pointer arithmetics. As for the parameters: when you call a function, all of the parameters sent to it will be **copied**. Because of this, when you do: `int i; myFunc(i);` **nothing** you do inside the function can change the i outside of the function, only use it. If you send a pointer to the data, you can change the data (but not the pointer).

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation Orka. You are right, I seem to be confused by the pointer address, what's stored at that address and that the pointer itself can have an address. I realized though that only with practicing I learn where my misunderstandings are. Thanks for taking the time to explain everything.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to set the return value (or the parameter) to &resultSet.  But we could know for sure if you showed the parameters to the function and the calling of the function.

Comment: Hogan, you got it right. I returned my resultSet (without the &) and adjusted my function from returning and int to to **char, now all works.